# CS0012: The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I got this error using a new "ASP.NET MVC 2 Empty Web Application" project:

> CS0012: The type
>   'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary'
>   is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference
>   to assembly 'System.Web.Routing,
>   Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Comment: for my case, it caused by branch changes, it can be solved by simply reopen the VS

Answer (score 11):

Update web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        ...
    </system.web>
    ...
</configuration>
```