# asp.net mvc no <assemblies> in webconfig

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an issue with one of my `.ascx` files, when I hover over a red `<%=Html.BeginForm` it says:

> The type RouteValueDictionary is defined in an assembly that is not referanced. You must add a referance to assemly System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Problem is I don't have any  in my web configs.
But I do have `System.Web.Routing` installed in my References.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CS0012: The type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828393/cs0012-the-type-system-web-routing-routevaluedictionary-is-defined-in-an-asse)

Comment: I took a look at this before posting.  Issue is that I do not have any <assemblies> at all, and when I do add it as described it does not solve the problem. I am working in MVC2.

Comment: Please share your web.config. Also, you have .ascx file in MVC?

Comment: Yes there are several ascx files in this MVC, they work with the forms