# Error When add Remote attribute to asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When i add `[Remote()]` attribute to a class property, the following exception gets throw:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Entities
{
    [Serializable]
    public class EmployeeEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
        [MaxLength(20)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\S*$", ErrorMessage = "No white space allowed")]
        [Remote("IsUserNameAvailable", "Employee",HttpMethod ="GET", ErrorMessage = "EmailId already exists in database.")]
```

Comment: `System.Web.Routing` assemly doesn't seem to be available. Can you try add it using web.config file? Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828393/cs0012-the-type-system-web-routing-routevaluedictionary-is-defined-in-an-asse

Comment: You said you use asp.net core,but why did you use `System.Web.Mvc`?It is the dll in asp.net.

Comment: Thank you Mosia that's working after i install Microsoft.AspNetCoreCore.Routing.

Answer (score 1):

Solved - After i install Microsoft.AspNetCoreCore.Routing.
The problem is using System.Web.Mvc in asp core project